# PHP don't return any json from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I want get MySQL database by PHP and AngularJS.

I make this:

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$rows = array();
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $db_pass, $db_name);
$quer = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Sheet1");
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($quer)) {
  $rows[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

But nothing return and when i set this as:

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$rows = array();
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $db_pass, $db_name);
$quer = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Sheet1");
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($quer)) {
  $rows = $data;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

I'll get only one last record

My main html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js'></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="App" ng-controller="mainController">
      <ul ng-repeat=" x in data">
        <li>{{x.id}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="mainController.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my Javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('database.php').then( function( response){
    $scope.data = response.data;
  });
});
```

Please for help i'm it's my first try in this.

Comment: `$rows = $data;` should be `$rows[] = $data;`. otherwise you will be overwriting the value. Closing as typo.

Comment: If your second script gives you one row but the first appears to give you nothing, that makes no sense. So I would look at your Angular code, thats where your issue will be.

Comment: Riggs is right, what you're claiming is impossible. Your first code example should be correct. You can verify that by using your browser's network tool to watch your AJAX request to database.php and looking at what the raw response is (click into the ajax request and then view the Response tab). If the data in there looks right then the problem is somewhere in your Javascript/Angular code instead. Personally I'd try `$scope.data = response;` - I see no evidence that your `response` object would have a `data` property in it. It's more likely to be an array. Did you check for console errors??

Comment: @ADyson console don't show any errors. First script even don't work as independent file so maybe it's some error in MySQL base?. When i change `echo json_encode($rows)` to `echo json_encode($rows[1])` it's works normal.

Comment: "even don't work" means what exactly? PHP error? Unexpected output? Please be clear and precise. Also you can do a `var_dump($rows);` just before the json_encode line to check the content of the array. It's also possible for json_encode to fail too. It will return `false` if it does, so you can easily check for that, and then you can use json_last_error_msg() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to find out why. Basically I'm saying you need to do some more thorough investigation and debugging to find precisely where the fault is occurring.

Comment: @ADyson I used `var_dump($rows);` and i get all records so array is working, when i add `json_last_error_msg()` i got `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` and in `RAW DATA` i got `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`. So MySQL is not converted to UTF-8 or my json must be converted. I tried `mb_convert_encoding($rows,  'UTF-8');` but nothing happend also nothing changed after convert MySQL base to `utf-8_polish_ci`.

Comment: have you tried (in addition to the above) `json_encode($rows, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`? See http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php . It's a little difficult to be certain without seeing the raw data. Also have you set the character set in your MySQL connection (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)? Try combinations of your suggestions and mine and see if you can get something working. P.S. the JSON.parse error is only because of the var_dump, it will go away when you remove that - obviously we're added non-JSON content to the response, which it doesn't like.

Comment: @ADyson Here is my raw data https://pastebin.com/EtvAPBjf i tried `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` and nothing changed also `mb_convert_encoding` doesn't work. Maybe my MySQL data is broken and just make wrong syntax JSON?.

Comment: what about setting the charset on your connection? Have you tried that? Have you tried all combinations of these various settings, as suggested? I doubt your data is completely broken, unless there are some characters in there which are not even UTF8